# How to show a 1 DOM object while hiding other DOM options with a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to js and i'm trying to show a pricing/plan based on a user's selection. I don't think this is the best way to do it but since I'm a beginner I'm not too sure on a more efficient approach.  Currently the script seems to hide my selector and I can't figure out why.  Any suggestions on how to make a better solution. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#plan-prices").change(function(){
                $( "#plan-prices option:selected").each(function(){
                                        if($(this).attr("value")=="starter-price"){
                                           $(".starter-plan").show();
                                           $(".small-plan").hide();
                                           $(".medium-plan").hide();
                                           $(".large-plan").hide();
                                           $(".enterprise-plan").hide();
                                          }
                                          if($(this).attr("value")=="small-price"){
                                           $(".starter-plan").hide();
                                           $(".small-plan").show();
                                           $(".medium-plan").hide();
                                           $(".large-plan").hide();
                                           $(".enterprise-plan").hide();
                                         }
                                         if($(this).attr("value")=="medium-price"){
                                           $(".starter-plan").hide();
                                           $(".small-plan").hide();
                                           $(".medium-plan").show();
                                           $(".large-plan").hide();
                                           $(".enterprise-plan").hide();
                                         }
                                          if($(this).attr("value")=="large-price"){
                                           $(".starter-plan").hide();
                                           $(".small-plan").hide();
                                           $(".medium-plan").hide();
                                           $(".large-plan").show();
                                           $(".enterprise-plan").hide();
                                         }
                                         if($(this).attr("value")=="enterprise-price"){
                                           $(".starter-plan").hide();
                                           $(".small-plan").hide();
                                           $(".medium-plan").hide();
                                           $(".large-plan").hide();
                                           $(".enterprise-plan").show();
                    }
                });
        }).change();
     });
</script>
```

My HTML

### $19.99 /mo

```
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 plan-free-trial">
     <h3>30 day Free Trial</h3>

</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 pricing-details">
    <div class="col-xs-12 feature-list">
         <h3 class="price-title">
                                    Starter Plan
                                </h3>

        <ul>
            <li class="plan-feature">1 to 50 Users</li>
            <li class=" starter-plan plan-feature">Unlimited Bandwidth</li>
            <li class="plan-feature">Unlimited Products</li>
            <li class="plan-feature">Unlimited Push Notifications</li>
            <li class="plan-feature">1 Entry Raffle For a Custom App Theme</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Small Business Plan -->
<div class="col-xs-12 small-plan  pricing-wrapper">
    <div class="col-xs-12 large-price">
         <h2><sup class="price-symbol">$</sup><span class="plan-price">49.99 </span><span class="month-abrev">/mo</span></h2>

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 plan-free-trial">
         <h3>30 day Free Trial</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 pricing-details">
        <div class="col-xs-12 feature-list">
             <h3 class="price-title">
                                    Starter Plan
                                </h3>

            <ul>
                <li class="plan-feature">1 to 50 Users</li>
                <li class=" starter-plan plan-feature">Unlimited Bandwidth</li>
                <li class="plan-feature">Unlimited Products</li>
                <li class="plan-feature">Unlimited Push Notifications</li>
                <li class="plan-feature">1 Entry Raffle For a Custom App Theme</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Medium Business Plan -->
    <div class="col-xs-12 medium-plan pricing-wrapper">
        <div class="col-xs-12 large-price">
             <h2><sup class="price-symbol">$</sup><span class="plan-price">99.99 </span><span class="month-abrev">/mo</span></h2>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 plan-free-trial">
             <h3>30 day Free Trial</h3>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 pricing-details">
            <div class="col-xs-12 feature-list">
                 <h3 class="price-title">
                                    Starter Plan
                                </h3>

                <ul>
                    <li class="plan-feature">1 to 50 Users</li>
                    <li class=" starter-plan plan-feature">Unlimited Bandwidth</li>
                    <li class="plan-feature">Unlimited Products</li>
                    <li class="plan-feature">Unlimited Push Notifications</li>
                    <li class="plan-feature">1 Entry Raffle For a Custom App Theme</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>-->
        <!-- Large Business Plan -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 large-plan  pricing-wrapper">
            <div class="col-xs-12 large-price">
                 <h2><sup class="price-symbol">$</sup><span class="plan-price">199.99 </span><span class="month-abrev">/mo</span></h2>

            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 plan-free-trial">
                 <h3>30 day Free Trial</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 pricing-details">
                <div class="col-xs-12 feature-list">
                     <h3 class="price-title">
                                    Starter Plan
                                </h3>

                    <ul>
                        <li class="plan-feature">1 to 50 Users</li>
                        <li class=" starter-plan plan-feature">Unlimited Bandwidth</li>
                        <li class="plan-feature">Unlimited Products</li>
                        <li class="plan-feature">Unlimited Push Notifications</li>
                        <li class="plan-feature">1 Entry Raffle For a Custom App Theme</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- ENTERPRISE Business Plan -->
            <div class="col-xs-12 enterprise-plan  pricing-wrapper">
                <div class="col-xs-12 large-price">
                     <h2><sup class="price-symbol">$</sup><span class="plan-price">599.99 </span><span class="month-abrev">/mo</span></h2>

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 plan-free-trial">
                     <h3>30 day Free Trial</h3>

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 pricing-details">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 feature-list">
                         <h3 class="price-title">
                                    Starter Plan
                                </h3>

                        <ul>
                            <li class="plan-feature">1 to 50 Users</li>
                            <li class=" starter-plan plan-feature">Unlimited Bandwidth</li>
                            <li class="plan-feature">Unlimited Products</li>
                            <li class="plan-feature">Unlimited Push Notifications</li>
                            <li class="plan-feature">1 Entry Raffle For a Custom App Theme</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                                <select class="form-control" name="plan-prices" id="plan-prices" aria-describedby="inputSuccess5Status" >

                                        <option class="starter-price" value="starter-price">$19.99</option>

                                        <option class="small-price" value="small-price" id="small-business-price">$49.99</option>

                                        <option class="medium-price" value="medium-price">$99.99</option>

                                        <option class="large-price" value="large-price">$199.99</option>

                                        <option class="enterprise-price" value="enterprise-price">$599.99</option>

                                    </select>
```

Comment: You might like to shift the indents a little to the left. Don't use tabs for indents, use spaces, usually 2 per indent is sufficient or 4 if you really like space.

Comment: Also, your HTML is broken. Many unclosed tags. You should look into a proper IDE.

Comment: simplify by half by hiding everything before your "if gauntlet", then instantly un-hiding the stuff you need. that way, you don't have to list every little hidden thing every single time. you can also replace all your IFs with a _switch_ statement

Comment: `#plan-prices` doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 0):

Looks quite simple.

Try :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#plan-prices").change(function () {
        $(".starter-plan, .pricing-wrapper").hide().filter("." + $(this).val().replace('price','.plan')).show();
    }).change();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten it a lot like this.  The idea is to hide everything once, then for the selected once, convert the price class name into a plan class name algorithmically and then show that one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#plan-prices").change(function () {
        $(".starter-plan, .small-plan, .medium-plan, .large-plan, .enterprise-plan").hide();
        $("#plan-prices option:selected").each(function () {
            var val = $(this).attr("value").replace("-price", "-plan");
            $("." + val).show();
        });
    }).change();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way to do it (assuming you are working with a multiselect and not a dropdown as indicated by your .each statement.) using toggle and inArray

```
 $(function(){
     var priceSelected = function(){             
         var selectedValues = [];
         $('#plan-prices option:selected').each(function(){
             selectedValues.push($(this).val());
         });
         $(".starter-plan").toggle($.inArray("starter_price", selectedValues));
         $(".small-plan").toggle($.inArray("small_price", selectedValues));
         $(".medium-plan").toggle($.inArray("medium_price", selectedValues));
         $(".large-plan").toggle($.inArray("large_price", selectedValues));
         $(".enterprise-plan").toggle($.inArray("enterprise_price", selectedValues));
     };
     $("#plan-prices").on('change', priceSelected);
     priceSelected();
 });
```